# Locking critical section in object used across multiple threads

Tags: c#, locking

I've got a class that is instantiated within any number of threads that are spooled up as needed.  This means that any number of instantiated versions of this class can be used at any one time, and there's a portion of this class that needs to be locked to prevent concurrent access.

To prevent data issues between the various threads, I needed a way to lock a section of code from the other instantiated versions of the class in other threads.  Since there can be multiple instantiated versions of this class running around, I can't just use a private member variable to lock (and I know not to use the Type, or anything publicly accessible); so I used a private static member variable.

Is that a reasonable approach to this problem?  Or is there a better solution?

Sample code below:

```
public class MyClass
  {
    private static object LockingVar = new object();

    public void MyPublicMethod()
    {
      lock (LockingVar)
      {
         // Do some critical code
      }
  }
```

**EDIT**

MyPublicMethod is making calls to a local SQLExpress instance, it can perform selects in addition to updates and inserts, so it needs to finish before another thread gets in there and mucks it up.

Comment: 1) you lock shared resources to prevent corruption, 2) if shared resources are instance based [ie multiple threads accessing a single class instance] your `LockingVar` [more commonly named SyncRoot] should be instance based 'private readonly object LockingVar', 3) if shared resources are static based [ie many instances, one per thread, each instance referencing a static list] then your lock should also be static. fwiw, i would avoid static anything, but we gotta do what we gotta do :)

Comment: Given your edit - can't you rely on database transactions to make sure that concurrent selects/inserts/updates don't corrupt each other, rather than using a fairly brutal lockin your calling code?

Comment: I would think so, except that it's not just doing database calls. It's also making changes to critical/shared data.  Does that change the situation any?  I realize at this point that I could have provided more details on my exact solution.

Comment: ahhh - if you updating shared data that is held in memory in your C# code, then you will need to provide some sort of synchronisation as in your example above.

Comment: According to here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) : *Best practice is to define a private object to lock on, or a private static object variable to protect data common to all instances.*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks fine to me. I'd also mark the LockingVar as readonly.

Comment: @RichardOD Only for my understanding, why to mark a private field as read only?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, with your sample code, you'll achieve a global critical section on the method for all instances of the class.

If that's what you're looking for (and you have to ask yourself if you really want to have only ever one thread running that method at a time), you can also use the `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]` which gets you basically the same feature.

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
public static void MyPublicMethod()
{
     // Do some critical code
}
```

Note: this amounts to write `lock(this){}` if it's a instance method or `lock(typeof(MyClass))` if it's a class (static) method. Both are frown upon, so your `lock(obj)` pattern is better.

Comment: Remove the static modifier if you only want to lock on a single instance and not on all the instances.

Answer (score 3):

From MSDN:

Best practice is to define a private object to lock on, or a private static object variable to protect data common to all instances.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx

Therefore your implementation seems to be right.